# Is there a more reliable and simple way to include php file

Tags: php

I use a method like this instead of using a global variable:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

switch ($page) {
    case 'note':
     include('note.php');
    break;
    case 'home':
     include('home.php');
    break;
    default:
      include('home.php');   
     break;
       }
```

Is there a faster and more reliable way to include files?

Comment: If your concerns are speed and reliability, the only mechanism that might be slighter better than `include` is `require` (because it'll abort on error). But both should be lightning fast and reliable anyway. Are you facing any specific problem? I somehow have the impression that you're wondering about the maintainability of your application design rather than its performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate and include like following:

```
$pageArr = ['note', 'home'];

if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pageArr)) {
 include $_GET['page'] . '.php';
} else {
 include 'default_file.php';
}
```